# How to feed OpenSSL HMAC function with the counter via CLI for rfc4226?

Tags: openssl, encoding

I have problems feeding the counter needed to compute a one-time password with OpenSSL HMAC via cli. I believe my problem is with encoding of the counter.I cannot reproduce the test vectors in RFC:

Count    Hexadecimal HMAC-SHA-1(secret, count)
   0        cc93cf18508d94934c64b65d8ba7667fb7cde4b0
   1        75a48a19d4cbe100644e8ac1397eea747a2d33ab

I've tried:

echo -n "1" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "12345678901234567890"

I've also tried to echo -e "\001".

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Since this appears to be about how to use a piece of software rather than the mathematical details of cryptography, it is probably more suitable for a site like superuser. I can migrate this there for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is close, but note that the counter is always **8 bytes** (big-endian). So if the counter numerical value is 1, it is fed to HMAC as bytes `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01`.

```
$ echo -e -n '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 12345678901234567890
(stdin)= cc93cf18508d94934c64b65d8ba7667fb7cde4b0

$ echo -e -n '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01' | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 12345678901234567890
(stdin)= 75a48a19d4cbe100644e8ac1397eea747a2d33ab
```

For comparison, if you're implementing it in Python:

```
key = b"12345678901234567890"
counter = 1
msg = struct.pack(">Q", counter)
result = hmac.HMAC(key, msg, hashlib.sha1)
```